# Cassandra 1.0.6 on adding the new node to current single node cluster

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql

We have cassandra 1.0.6 with single node cluster, what are the steps need to be considered while adding new node of same cassandra version.

**Any we need to add the second node without restarting the current 1st node.**

Comment: I highly recommend using a more-recent version of Cassandra (at least 2.1 or 2.2) and upgrading before expanding your cluster.  You're missing out on **5 years** of bug fixes and forcing yourself into a world of Hector/Thrift-based connection hell.

Comment: How can we upgrade 1.0.6 to 2.1 or 2.2 version without losing any data ?

Comment: How much data are you talking about here?  In theory, you can run an upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1, 1.1 to 1.2, 1.2 to 2.0, and then 2.0 to 2.1.  Honestly though, it might be a better idea to build a new 2-node cluster and load your data fresh.

Comment: We are upgrading from 1.0.6 to 1.2.9 version, what are steps we need to execute. (we have around 30GB of live data)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89383/upgrading-cassandra-from-1-1-0-to-latest/89861#89861

Answer (score 1):

The following step should be sufficient for your case.

**node0** : old node

**node1** : new node

1. Install Cassandra on **nodes1** (version 1.0.6 in your case)
2. Change these properties in cassandra.yaml file

   - *cluster_name* : same as in **node0**
   - *listen_address* : ip of **node1**
   - *rpc_address* : ip of **node1**
   - *seeds* : ip of the **node0**
   - *endpoint_snitch* : change this to *GossipingPropertyFileSnitch* in both nodes
3. Ensure that both node's cassandra-rackdc.properties files have same *dc* values.
4. Now start your **node1** normally.

The **node1** will add itself to the datacenter of **node0** and fetch the data its been assigned to have.

If this does not work go through this link : [Adding nodes to an existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html). Would help.

Comment: Do we need to run repair on 1st node after starting the 2nd node ?

Comment: If everything started fine, without any complications then it would be wise to do `nodetool cleanup` on each node rather than `nodetool repair`. This will **Cleans up keyspaces and partition keys no longer belonging to a node**.